# Django add non-nullable field (ForeignKey)

Tags: django, django-models, foreign-keys, django-migrations

I need to add `ForeignKey` field to model, but `makemigrations` returns error to set default. But I won't any default value.

For example

```
@python_2_unicode_compatible
class Doctor(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    surname = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    middlename = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    specialization = models.ForeignKey('Specialization', blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s %s" % (self.name, self.surname)

@python_2_unicode_compatible
class Specialization(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    #spec_table_name = models.ForeignKey('SpecializationTable')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Consultation(models.Model):
    client_id = models.ForeignKey('Client')
    doctor_id = models.ForeignKey('Doctor')

    #how to dropdown from doctor
    #record_id = models.ForeignKey(Specialization)

@python_2_unicode_compatible
class SpecializationTable(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class SpecializationTableRow(models.Model):
    row_name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    row_description = models.CharField(max_length=999)
    row_required = models.BooleanField()
    table_name = models.ForeignKey(SpecializationTable)
```

That is the model I already have, when I try to uncomment `ForeignKey` in `Specialization` - error appers. If I delete all migrations, and start from scratch - there would be no error.

And moreover - I have no records at all (clean db).

How to pass this error, and don't drop\create db from scratch ?

Comment: specify `blank=True` to that field.

Comment: @MuhammadShoaib but everyone said that `null` field in Db - movetone. If I need to add fields in furthere - there should be a lot of `null`. Is there any other way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem from django's point of view is that it has to know what to do with existing records of the `Specialization` model. It cannot know that there aren't any of those.

If you have a clean db, as you say, you can unapply the migrations to the point where the model in question is created. Let's assume `Specialization` is created in a migration called `0003_*`, you can call:

```
> python manage.py migrate <app_name> 0002
```

Then you can delete all migration files in the app starting from `0003`. Then, `makemigrations` will work again. If it it is created in `0001`, you must do:

```
> python manage.py migrate <app_name> zero
```

This being said, the default value you provide during `makemigrations` is not preserved in any way (it will only be applied to existing records during `migrate`). So, if you have an empty database, providing any value (e.g. `1`) will not have any effect at all.

Comment: I did almost same way, except I didn't know about `zero`, so thanks. But imagine, I work on production, can I do this trick? I guess no, altering fields with `null` value also bad prop. I fully understand that this my faul to not to think about architecture well, but hey, why there is no solution with low pain cost?

Comment: There can be no low pain here. Imagine, in production, if you already have records and you add a non-nullable field, at some point you will have to decide what value you want to give those records...